# How to properly deal with KVO notifications when an managed object turns into a fault?

Tags: iphone, core-data

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202-CJBDBHCB):

> When Core Data turns an object into a
>   fault, key-value observing (KVO)
>   change notifications (see Key-Value
>   Observing Programming Guide) are sent
>   for the object’s properties. If you
>   are observing properties of an object
>   that is turned into a fault and the
>   fault is subsequently realized, you
>   receive change notifications for
>   properties whose values have not in
>   fact changed.

So if an object turns into a fault, Core Data does send KVO notifications for changed properties? So I must always check for isFault == NO before beeing happy about the notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is one solution.  A better solution would be to stop observing the object when it gets turned into a fault.  In practice, except for in low memory situations, you know when an object is going to be turned into a fault and can plan for it.

Comment: To sum up: I'm strongly discouraged from using NSManagedObject with KVO? Because I don't want my KVO depends on faulting and make any glue code to make it works with NSManagedObject. What would you recommend? There are no useful tips in Core Data programming guide too :( http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202

Comment: Not at all.  It is just a matter of learning where the edges are.

Answer (score 7):

`isFault` is not reliable because `isFault` may still returns NO when KVO notifications are sent. One should check `faultingState` for that:

> faultingState Returns a value that indicates the faulting state of the
>   receiver.
>
> - (NSUInteger)faultingState Return Value 0 if the object is fully initialized as a managed object and not transitioning to or from
>     another state, otherwise some other value.
>
> Discussion The method allow you to determine if an object is in a
>   transitional phase when receiving a key-value observing change
>   notification.